# How to proceed with streamlines

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

I am starting with describing the streamlines of velocity fields.

Let's work out the following example so as to see where I get stuck:

$$v(x, y, z) = x \hat{i} + y \hat{j} - x \hat{k}$$

Now we set up the differential equation for the field lines:

$$\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{y} = - \frac{dz}{x}$$

From here on I do not understand why we do what we do; the solution states:

> Thus, $z + x = C_1$, $y = C_2 x$. The streamlines are straight halflines emanating from the z-axis
>   and perpendicular to the vector $\hat{i} + \hat{k}$

Please explain why.

Comment: $\dfrac{dx}x=-\dfrac{dz}x\implies dx+dz=0\implies x+z=C_1$. You can get the second equation by equating $\dfrac{dx}x$ and $\dfrac{dy}y$ and integrating in a similar manner.